# Is it possible to set a display name different to its real name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, rename

Considering any folder, is it possible to set a different display name for it without changing the real system name?

For example, to have a folder on any drive, like `D:\foo` and let it show up in windows explorer with the name `foobar` instead of `foo`.

I'm thinking of the "Program Files" or "Users" folder which are localized and have a different display name. So I guess it should be possible somehow...

Comment: The _Users_ folders is localized through the Explorer shell as a Shell folder.

Comment: Does this mean it's more or less hardcoded in the Explorer?

Comment: The list of shell folders is hardcoded.  What the shell folders point to isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could presumably use [junctions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) or [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to link the real folder to the 'new' display name. Not sure if it'll work with hiding the original folder though.

Comment: And probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Bit easier using this http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Comment: @Shinrai: Actually it's pretty darn easy.  Just hide the real folder and present a Junction.  Boom.

Comment: @surfasb - When I said 'trouble' I meant more 'added complexity to your configuration' rather than 'difficulty'.  It's not hard, you're right.

Comment: True, it isn't point and click.  But I'd rather let the OP make that cost/benefit analysis.